# Passing an input into a function and calling the function on a button click

Tags: angular, typescript

My issue is that I have to call updateCard(), with uid and name, both strings.
However, name is coming up undefined or invalid each time I call the function. 
What would be a good way to pass the input name to the function when the udpate button is pressed.
I know the function works from testing. I have tried ngModel and passing the id into the function.

```
<div>{{card.name}}
            <form>
                Name: <input type="text" id = "name" [(ngModel)] = name><br>
                <input type="button" value="Update Name" (click)='bcService.updateCard(card.id, name)'>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: bcService.updateCard(card.id, name) are you trying to send the value of the input box?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by adding ngModelOptions as standalone?

```
<input type="text" id = "name" [(ngModel)] = "name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Comment: I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your situation, I would work with reactive form. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
**Update**
you can do somthing like this:

```
<div>
    <span>{{card.name}}</span>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update Name">
    </form>
</div>
```

```
form:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
    id:new FormControl(""),
    name:new FormControl("")
  });

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.bcService.updateCard(
      this.form.get("id").value,
      this.form.get("name").value
      );
  }
```

Comment: Why would you suggest this for such a simple use case?

Comment: @DamianC u are right, the case is so simple for reactive, I use R forms a lot that why I didn't analyse the situation before posting

Comment: It might be helpful to show how to use reactive forms in this scenario.

Comment: Yeah I just posted an example, but I think your solution should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to use card.name ?

```
<div>
    <span>{{card.name}}</span>
    <form>
        Name: <input type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="card.name"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Update Name" (click)="bcService.updateCard(card.id, card.name)">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: card.name is the value from my database. Name is the input that im trying to update that value with.

Comment: Any reason they can't point to the variable since they are same data?

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work. use event.value like below

```
<input type="button" value="Update Name" (click)='bcService.updateCard(card.id, 
 event.value)'>
```